# GraphQL and Mongoose: When querying, populate references in subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

This is my schema, and in MongoDB I have separate collections for users, events and movies due to the large number of events and movies:

```
type Event {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!
  creator: User!
}
type Movie {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  releaseDate: String
}
type MovieStatus {
  movie: Movie
  status: StatusEnum  // WATCHED, PLANNING_TO_WATCH
}
type User {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  createdEvents: [Event!]
  movies: [MovieStatus!]
}
```

And I want to create the following query:

```
query {
  user(id: "12345") {
    id
    firstName
    createdEvents{
      id
      title
      description
    }
    movies{
      movie {
        id 
        title 
        releaseDate
      }
      status
    }
  }
}
```

I have no problem getting the events, by including this in my resolvers:

```
User: {
    createdEvents: ({ createdEvents }) =>
      Event.find({ _id: { $in: createdEvents } }),
  },
```

But I can't figure out how to access the movie id, title and release dates.

Comment: you have to resolve `User.movies` - array of `MovieStatus` first

Comment: @xadm - still pretty new to this. Would you be so kind as to explain that?

Comment: what is stored in 'movies' ? list of (movie id + status) ? get list of ids, find movies, then connect result with statuses using source pairs ... return array of objects `{ status, movie {id, title, release} }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
movies: ({ movies }) => {
  return Promise.all(
    movies.map(async (m) => {
      const movie = m
      movie.movie = await Movie.findById(movie.movie)
      return movie
    })
  )
}
```